# Docusign Add Integrator Key not showing on docusign account admin panel

Tags: docusignapi

When i login to my docusign live account admin panel, i can not see any add integrator key button under API and Keys menu.

[image]

So now, how can i generate integrator key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Live `Integrator Keys` cannot be created. You must promote a Demo `Integrator Key` to a Live key. Promoting a Demo key is quite simple. You'll need to follow the process in this [link](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-docusign-go-live-process-now-automated/).

Essentially, you'll mark an `Integrator Key` to be promoted to the live environment. After a review is completed, the key is eligible to "Go Live." Note: before the key is available in a live environment, the process will be pending for 4-24 hours. Afterwards, the `Integratory Key` will be visible on your live account's "API and Keys" section.